# Graph representation of sliding puzzle

Tags: java, graph-theory

I need to represent a sliding puzzle that goes from **2x2** to **4x4** using graphs. I am aware that a state of the puzzle can represent a vertex and the other possibilities are connected with edges. I am not sure how to begin and how to create the vertices and the connections with edges. For example, a **3x3** puzzle has 9! vertices, but how can I create that graph in java?

Comment: What do you mean by "sliding puzzle"?

Comment: Are you looking for the graphical representation or the logical one ?

Comment: @c0der the logical one

Comment: A simple representation for a node can be an nxn matrix.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [JGraphT](https://jgrapht.org/) library. 
Have a look at [Graph](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/index.html?org/jgrapht/Graph.html) interface implementations for the supported graphs.